# Centered div with max-width and content to both sides

Tags: html, css, width

Let say I have a layout with 3 columns:

```
| left sidebar |       content        | right sidebar |
```

Each column is a div with *float: left*.

I'd like to have the content div always centered, but also set a *max-width* to it:

```
| left sidebar | centered + max width | right sidebar |
```

The total width of the 3 columns should always be 100%, so the two sidebars would have adapt and fill the remaining space.

So in a very big screen it would look like this:

```
|        left sidebar        |       content        |        right sidebar        |
```

As if the content div had margin: *0 auto* (but with the two divs at the sides instead of empty space).

Is it possible to do such a thing with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Using **flexbox** is quite a simple

```css
*{margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;} html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}
div{ border: 1px solid #000;}

/* here you go */
.flex{ display: flex; }
.grow-1{ flex: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>left sidebar</div>
  <div class="grow-1">content</div>
  <div>right sidebar</div>
</div>
```

adding the class `grow-1` to other elements:

```css
*{margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;} html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}
div{ border: 1px solid #000;}

/* here you go */
.flex{ display: flex; }
.grow-1{ flex: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="grow-1">left sidebar</div>
  <div class="grow-1">content</div>
  <div class="grow-1">right sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed since `float: left` was the only solution.

A simpler alternative is to use `display` properties. An example would be something like this:

```
div#wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
div#left-sidebar,
div#content,
div#right-sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

The `table-cell` property allows the divs to behave like cells in a table *without actually using a table* — the best of both worlds.

The properties in the `wrapper` div allow you to specify the width and affect how the cells are distributed.

A better solution would be to use `flex-box`. However, that only works in modern browsers, so you might have to hold off till you can be sure that there’s no IE lurking about. It’s also a bit harder to learn, but much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to avoid the use `flex-box` due to some older browsers not supporting it...

You could use `display` table properties in the `css`. A `@media` query can then be utilized to effectively set the `max-width` of your `content` `div` *(i.e. the middle column)*.

**Example media query:**

```css
@media (min-width: 300px) {
    .middle {
        width: 100px !important;
    }
}
```

*Note regarding the media query:* The `width` value for the `.middle` class should equal the `@media` queries `min-width` value divided by three. The `width` value within this context then behaves similar to `max-width`.

For example; if you want the `max-width` of the middle column to be `300px`, then you set the `min-width` value for the `@media` query to `900px`. Given this configuration the width of the middle column would remain flexible until the browser width exceeds `900px` wide, at which point the middle column width is fixed at `300px` wide.

**Code snippet:**

Here is the full code snippet, including both `html` and `css`:

```css
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: table;
    background: #BADA55;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.wrapper > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.middle {
    background: #C0FFEE;
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    /*
     * The 'width' value below should be the @media 
     * queries 'min-width' value (above) divided by three.
     *
     * The 'width' value below is then behaves similar
     * to 'max-width'.
     */
    .middle {
        width: 250px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div>left sidebar</div>
        <div class="middle">content</div>
        <div>right sidebar</div>
    </div>
 </body>
```